# Good mobile applications to aid development?

Tags: iphone, blackberry, mobile

I've had a Blackberry for close to a year now, and recently got an iPod Touch.  I've been wondering, with all the available technology in my pocket, is there anything I can use to help with the development process?

Perhaps something to get on a VPN?

Maybe something to view SVN/CVS commits?

Any source code viewers, with syntax highlighting and code folding?

Anything to connect to Remote Desktop or VNC?

Any Agile Collaboration tools, like [Skinnyboard](http://www.skinnyboard.com)?

Please, share what you use, and take this as an opportunity to shamelessly plug your own development related iPhone/Blackberry application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have ScrumTools on my iPod Touch.  It's a pretty basic tool that has planning poker cards, and a timer for time boxing.  Will it change the way you work?  Not by a long shot.  But it's nice to have.